# How to extract ACPI tables from .ISO file?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, iso, acpi

I am in need of ACPI tables (DSDT) that comes with Linux ISOs.

Why?

Because i am compiling a custom kernel which includes modules that require certain things to be enabled in the ACPI, and the kernel source has support for a feature that allows overriding the default ACPI `(CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT_FILE)`, means i could :

1. Extract the ACPI tables from the ISO
2. Modify them to my needs
3. Compile them together with the ISO

The question is how? And is that even possible?

Here is the directory tree of the ISO, if neccesary:

```
    ├── boot
│   ├── grub
│   │   ├── efi.img
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   │   │   └── unicode.pf2
│   │   ├── grub.cfg
│   │   └── TRANS.TBL
│   └── TRANS.TBL
├── efi
│   ├── boot
│   │   ├── bootia32.efi
│   │   ├── bootx64.efi
│   │   ├── grubx64.efi
│   │   └── TRANS.TBL
│   ├── RemixOS
│   │   ├── bootia32.efi
│   │   ├── BOOTx64.EFI
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   ├── DejaVuSansMono-18.pf2
│   │   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   │   │   └── unicode.pf2
│   │   ├── grub.cfg
│   │   ├── grubenv
│   │   ├── grubx64.efi
│   │   ├── i386-efi
│   │   │   ├── exfat.mod
│   │   │   ├── ntfs.mod
│   │   │   └── TRANS.TBL
│   │   ├── theme
│   │   │   ├── icons
│   │   │   │   ├── android-x86.png
│   │   │   │   ├── arch.png
│   │   │   │   ├── debian.png
│   │   │   │   ├── fedora.png
│   │   │   │   ├── frugalware.png
│   │   │   │   ├── gentoo.png
│   │   │   │   ├── gnu-linux.png
│   │   │   │   ├── invaders.png
│   │   │   │   ├── kubuntu.png
│   │   │   │   ├── linuxmint.png
│   │   │   │   ├── mageia.png
│   │   │   │   ├── mandriva.png
│   │   │   │   ├── opensuse.png
│   │   │   │   ├── sabayon.png
│   │   │   │   ├── shutdown.png
│   │   │   │   ├── slackware.png
│   │   │   │   ├── theme.png
│   │   │   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   │   │   │   ├── ubuntu.png
│   │   │   │   └── windows.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_c.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_e.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_ne.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_n.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_nw.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_se.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_s.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_sw.png
│   │   │   ├── menu_bkg_w.png
│   │   │   ├── Oxygen.jpg
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_c.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_e.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_ne.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_n.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_nw.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_se.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_s.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_sw.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_bar_w.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_highlight_c.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_highlight_e.png
│   │   │   ├── progress_highlight_w.png
│   │   │   ├── Sans-10.pf2
│   │   │   ├── Sans-12.pf2
│   │   │   ├── Sans-14.pf2
│   │   │   ├── sb_frame_c.png
│   │   │   ├── sb_frame_n.png
│   │   │   ├── sb_frame_s.png
│   │   │   ├── sb_thumb_c.png
│   │   │   ├── sb_thumb_n.png
│   │   │   ├── sb_thumb_s.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_c.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_e.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_ne.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_n.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_nw.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_se.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_s.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_sw.png
│   │   │   ├── select_bkg_w.png
│   │   │   ├── theme.txt
│   │   │   └── TRANS.TBL
│   │   ├── theme.cfg
│   │   ├── themes
│   │   │   ├── Aurora-Penguinis
│   │   │   │   ├── background.png
│   │   │   │   ├── icons
│   │   │   │   │   ├── antergos.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── arch.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── chakra.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── debian.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── deepin.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── elementary.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── fedora.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── gentoo.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── gnu-linux.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── kaos.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── korora.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── kubuntu.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── lfs.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── linuxmint.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── lubuntu.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── mageia.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── manjaro.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── opensuse.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── remixos.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── siduction.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ubuntu.png
│   │   │   │   │   ├── windows.png
│   │   │   │   │   └── xubuntu.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_c.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_e.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_ne.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_n.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_nw.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_se.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_s.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_sw.png
│   │   │   │   ├── select_w.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_c.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_e.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_ne.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_n.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_nw.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_se.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_s.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_sw.png
│   │   │   │   ├── terminal_box_w.png
│   │   │   │   ├── theme.cfg
│   │   │   │   ├── theme.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   │   │   │   └── unifont-regular-16.pf2
│   │   │   └── TRANS.TBL
│   │   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   │   └── x86_64-efi
│   │       ├── exfat.mod
│   │       ├── ntfs.mod
│   │       └── TRANS.TBL
│   └── TRANS.TBL
├── info.ini
├── initrd.img
├── install.img
├── isolinux
│   ├── boot.cat
│   ├── isolinux.bin
│   ├── isolinux.cfg
│   ├── remixos.png
│   ├── TRANS.TBL
│   └── vesamenu.c32
├── kernel
├── ramdisk.img
├── system.sfs
└── TRANS.TBL
```

Running Ubuntu 14.04.05 AMD64

Comment: ACPI tables normally come from the BIOS/firmware, not off disk. You'd normally dump the ones from your BIOS and modify them, if required. Not that I'd expect that to work, since if the BIOS isn't setting up those things, they probably won't work.